# Can curl external service inside container with proxy but not request from java / spring boot (503 by timeout)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, proxy

I'm trying to request a **external service** on my project, I can curl it inside de docker container and behind a proxy and get a valid response.

```
// Request example
curl https://api.something.com
```

The request is **https**.

But when the request is made from the java code (inside the container) I'm getting *http 503* by timeout.

> TLDR: What I'm believe the problem is...the proxy Isn't being applied on java / Spring boot.

My application.properties is:

```
server.address=0.0.0.0
```

I set the proxy variables on .mvn/jvm.config and works only to download the maven packages.

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxy_host>
-Dhttp.proxyPort=<proxy_port>
-Dhttps.proxyHost=<proxy_host>
-Dhttps.proxyPort=<proxy_port>
```

I also tried to add on jvm.config:

```
-Dhttp.setProxy=true
-Dhttps.setProxy=true
-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true
```

But for some reason the configuration isn't applied on the code.

```
public T getRequest(String url, Class<T> typeClass) {
        try {
            ResponseEntity<T> responseEntity = this.REST_TEMPLATE.getForEntity(url, typeClass);
            return responseEntity.getBody();
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(e.getStatusCode(), e.getResponseBodyAsString());
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE, "Serviço indisponivel", e);
        }
}
```

I also tried to add the proxy variables on the **RestTemplate** constructor (503 by timeout):

```
InetSocketAddress inetSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(this.PROXY_HOST, this.PROXY_PORT);
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, inetSocketAddress);
SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
requestFactory.setProxy(proxy);
this.REST_TEMPLATE = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11-slim

ENV https_proxy <proxy_host>:<proxy_port>
ENV http_proxy <proxy_host>:<proxy_port>
ENV HTTP_PROXY <proxy_host>:<proxy_port>
ENV HTTPS_PROXY <proxy_host>:<proxy_port>

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ /app/
RUN mvn package
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

And my pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>something</groupId>
    <artifactId>something</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>something</name>
    <description>something</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And as I said before, I can curl the service with no problem inside the container, but if I add the **no_proxy** variable inside the Dockerfile, I also get **503 by timeout** from curl.

So what I'm believe the problem is...the proxy Isn't being applied on java.

Can someone help me? The java / Spring boot configuration is sometimes very confusing.

*EDIT: I found the solution, for me I had to add the proxy information as java parameters.

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=*** -Dhttp.proxyPort=**** -Dhttps.proxyHost=**** -Dhttps.proxyPort=**** -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=database  -jar app.jar
```

Comment: Facing the same issue, I have a feeling that proxy configuration is needed at the cluster level, reading about it and will update if I find something.

Comment: I forgot to add the solution I found... I'll update the question.

Comment: Thanks, that would be helpful